# Can feature content be configured in lightning experience

Tags: lightning-experience, content, files, libraries

In SFDC Classic,I'm able to select content/files to “feature” and they appear in a featured section under libraries

I cannot find the same featured content files list in lightning experience.

Can any one of you please confirm , whether this can be configured in lightning experience or not .

FYR , I'm attaching the "featured content" list which is displayed in salesforce classic.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what I have read from the [release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/lex_gaps_limitations_files_and_content.htm) and [online documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=content_workspace.htm&type=0), this feature does not seem available in lightning experience, as it falls under the category of Managing Libraries which the release notes state as Not Available in LEX:

> Features Not Available in Lightning Experience
>
> - Documents
> - Salesforce CRM Content, including creating and ***managing libraries***,    content deliveries, and sharing files with libraries
> - File sharing with people and groups (except by posting to feeds)
> - File syncing
> - Freeze sharing (a new feature available only in Salesforce Classic in    the Winter ’16 release)